# Change a component props based on another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, render, conditional-operator

*Problem :*
I  need to change two components based on an onclick event. The function displayed on the onclick event `handleChange` has a prop 'text' . I need to change the value of the prop 3 times whenever I run the onclick event.

**1.**
I have a chip component(first component) which I want to change its text and color whenever my button(second component) it's clicked; the button will change its text as well. So I did with conditional rendering and my onclick event in my button.

**The thing here is that I have 3 states in which I want to change my chip and button, but only can make it with two** :

-default value which I apply when creating the state const with useState:

```
const [change, setChange] = useState("Pending");
```

-the value I pass to the event in the button:

```
<Button variant="contained" onClick={() => handleChange("hello")}>
```

**2.**

Besides the first button I have another button which I want to hide whenever my third state of chip changes.

I have 3 states : hello,pending,cancel.

When  first button and chip change to *cancel* I want to hide my third button.

I tried to make a switch statement to solve the problem of the 3 states but **I don't know how to use it. I don't know how to pass the 3 values**(hello,pending,cancel.) **inside the button either.**

[Here is my code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/chip-forked-j1sl5)

*Note: I am new in code sandbox so please tell me is you see the changes bcs I don't manage well enough the platform*

Comment: @oxygen https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox

Comment: @oxygen It’s just as easy to explain/expound/etc here, too, and use SO in the way it’s intended.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks !  but I didn't catch what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your three states are in order

```
const state = ["pending", "hello", "cancel"];
const [change, setChange] = useState(0);

function handleChange() {
  setChange(prevState => prevState === 2 ? 0 : prevState + 1);
}
  
const style = [
  {color: 'secondary'},
  {color: 'primary'},
  {style: {backgroundColor:"#7ed6df"}}
];

return (
  <>
    <Chip label={state[change]} {...style[change]} />
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleChange}>
      {state[change]}
    </Button>
    {change !== 2 && <Button variant="contained">Disappear</Button>}
  </>
);
```

Comment: I am actually having trouble with understanding this line about hiding the button : `change !== 2 &&` .. why is   `!== 2` instead of `=== 2`  ?

Comment: The button disappears if state is `cancel` hence appears if `change !== 2`

Comment: Hey I'm back again hehe... can you please help me one more time ?. In the function _handle Change_. we use ternary operator. It's totally fine but how can I change the condition to avoid that when the array it has ended the prevState should stop changing ? I tried changing the value of `0` per another one that does not exist in the array but it does not work.

Comment: @Karol Do you want your `handleChange` to only run once through 0 to 2 and never run after `change` gets to 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236186/discussion-between-karol-and-hamidreza).